# C++ String to String Array by Delimeter

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a file that is outputting information into a class.  Specifically one of the strings I am trying to output will go into a vector.  The problem is that I am trying to take a string (in this case of interests) which would be formatted:

```
interest_string = "food, exercise, stuff"
```

So basically I want to turn the string above into a string of arrays or somehow copy the above string to a vector in each individual string separated by the comma delimeter.

```
void Client::readClients() {
    string line;


    while (getline( this->clients, line ))
    {

        string interest_num_string, interest_string;

        istringstream clients( line );
        getline( clients, this->sex, ' ' );
        getline( clients, this->name, ',' );
        getline( clients, this->phone, ' ' );
        getline( clients, interest_num_string, ' ' );
        getline( clients, interest_string, '.' );

        this->interests = atoi(interest_num_string.c_str());

        cout << this->sex << "\n" << this->name << "\n" << this->phone << "\n" << interest_num_string << "\n" << interest_string;
    }

    this->clients.close();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the problem here. You seem to be filling up your structure/class fields pretty fine with `istringstream`

Comment: on the interest_string I grab the line that ends with a . but the items before it are seperated by comas like "item, item, item."  I was going to try and seperate these by the commas also.  Im guessing I can run the same function for these and copy to the vector?

Comment: I think that's what he's asking since it seems to be the only piece missing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  an alternate signature for `getline` is

`istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str, char delim );`

`strtok` in C is also a viable option that isn't too brutal on low-level string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vector or other suitable container. You will need to create a "person" class that will contain all of the data you read in and place into the container.

```
void Client::readClients(std::vector<MyClass*>& myPeople)
{
    //  ... other parts of your code

    // Create a person
    pointerToPerson = new Person();

    // read them in
    getline(clients, pointerToPerson->field, ' ');

    // After you load a person just add them to the vector
    myPeople.push_back(pointerToPerson);

    // more of your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple c++ piece of code :

```
  string s = "abc,def,ghi";
  stringstream ss(s);
  string a,b,c;
  ss >> a ; ss.ignore() ; ss >> b ; ss.ignore() ; ss >> c;    
  cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
```

Output :

abc def ghi